# Stratifying Trees

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, tree-care, nut-trees

I'm stratifying some maple trees, and others to grow for my future tree nursery, and I'm new to it. I stratified some maples by placing them in the fridge for six weeks, then they have been out for two.

My maple seeds look to be crumbling now. Should I start them without refrigeration? What should I do now, wait for the seeds another two weeks? Should I refrigerate them longer, or do a winter outdoors in a prepped spot?

I also have pecans, peaches, and fruit trees like apples, oranges, lemons, and others.

Comment: How do you place them in the fridge? In soil? Moist? Tell more about your method, since that is crucial. Best way is to let nature do the work, put the seeds in a pot with sand or soil outside, and wait till next spring.

Comment: I place them in the bottom drawer in a Ziploc bag full of moist potting soil mix. It's about 42° in the door.

Comment: That sounds like the proper way to do this, I have read that maple sometimes needs colder [(41F or 37.4F)](https://www.wikihow.com/Germinate-Maple-Tree-Seeds), but I am not sure if one degree would really make a difference.